# Django Forms - Different Versions

Tags: python, django

I am learning django so i looked over a tutorial and then i am looking over another one now. So  there are two versions of Signup form i came acrosss.

**1st Version:**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class MyRegForm(UserCreationForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields =('username','email','password','password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user=super(UserCreationForm,self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Looking at the first version i was able to understand that  i can even make a new  form by just making this simple class extending from class like this:

```
from django import forms
from models import Article

class ArtForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('title', 'body', 'pub_data', 'thumb')
```

**2nd Version:**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignupForm(forms.Forms):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    pass1 = forms.CharField(max_length=20,widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    pass2 = forms.CharField(max_length=20,widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value==False))

    def clean_username(self):
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=self.cleaned_data['username'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return self.cleaned_data['username']
        raise forms.ValidationError("The Username is already in use. Please Choose Another")

    def clean_pass2(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['pass2']!=self.cleaned_data['pass1']:
              raise forms.ValidationError("The two passwords should match")
        return self.cleaned_data['pass2']

    def save(self):
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(username=self.cleaned_data['username'],
                                            email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
                                            password=self.cleaned_data['pass1'])
        return new_user
```

In this second version we have to setup everything on our own, seems we are having a bit more power being able to add custom validation to it. The save function here seems weird , i dont see in object.save() call in it. It just returns the object. 
So which version should be used professionally? 
The second version does not have any Meta data in it. I think we can actually mix both kind of versions, but what is missing from both of them and which ones is more generally used?

Answer (score 1):

The second version is a plain form, not a model form. It creates the User object by calling `create_user`, which instantiates and saves it, so there is no need to call save explicitly.

Generally if you are dealing with model objects, it's usually better to use a ModelForm. In the case of the User object, there is the additional complication that you need to deal with hashing the password - `create_user` calls `user.set_password`, which does this. The first version inherits from UserCreationForm which calls set_password directly on the newly-created User instance. If you're creating Users, I would always say to subclass that UserCreationForm if possible.

Comment: Suppose i want to do custom validation like it has been done in the normal Forms(2nd version), username already in use etc etc. How will i be doing that in ModelForms? do i just add methods with clean_ as in normal forms?

Comment: Yes. Apart from the ability to call save, and get initial data from a model object, ModelForms work exactly the same as normal forms: you can define `clean_<fieldname>` and `clean` methods as usual.

Comment: Yes, the same applies about validation. clean_username would be a method in your form (ModelForm or normal form) to perform a field validation. clean_foo methods, to be executed, require only that the foo field exists in the form class, either by being in fields or not in exclude, or being an explicit field

Comment: So is this safe to assume that ModelForm is an subclass of Forms and thus everything that works in Forms will be actually working in ModelForm. (of course not vice versa)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the first one is a lot cleaner, but if you need to do special `User` creation that involves data that can't be attained from the form, or you want to clean your data in a very specific way, it might be worth to use some of the methods from the second, but even with those changes, there is probably not a need to use something other than a `ModelForm`